# Filter out all instances of a div class using cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, cheerio

Cheerio / nodeJS newbie here... save the vitriol for the real villains.

I am trying to extract the `title` (in this instance "Alfacash") from div class `exchange-card-small-logo` > a > img. There could be several instances of this div class in the HTML. I am trying to extract the `title` from each of the instances.

[image]

`console.log` won't get hit in the following:

```
axios.get("https://cryptoradar.co/exchanges")
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)

        $('.exchange-card-small-logo', html).each(function () {
            console.log($(this).length)
        })
```

And both of these `log` return 0:

```
const elems = $('.exchange-card-small-logo', html);
console.log(elems.length);
console.log(elems.toArray().length);
```

Also, this:

```
const elems = $('.exchange-card-small-logo', html);
console.log(elems);
```

returns:

```
LoadedCheerio {
  length: 0,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array],
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *1]
  },
  prevObject: LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array]
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
      '0': [Node],
      length: 1,
      options: [Object],
      _root: [Circular *1]
    },
    prevObject: LoadedCheerio {
      length: 0,
      options: [Object],
      _root: [LoadedCheerio]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the CSS selector: `#results > div > div.main-container.grid-flex > div:nth-child(1) > div.exchange-card-small-images > div.exchange-card-small-logo`.

I can't get the hierarchy right all the way down to that div class using cheerio. Is there a way to filter out all instances of this class without traversing all the path?

Comment: Why not simply `.exchange-card-small-logo` ? It will select all instances

Comment: It's coming back empty.

Comment: Empty? That's weird, because the element is clearly here in the HTML structure. Are you sure your Cheerio selector is running against what you showed above? And it doesn't run _before_ the HTML is rendered or anything?

Comment: @JeremyThille edited question with code snippet.

Comment: Cheerio is a pain to work with. It's a weird library. The documentation says it's basically server-side jQuery, but it's actually significantly different. Try `$('.exchange-card-small-logo').toArray().forEach( ... )`, or `const elems = $('.exchange-card-small-logo'); for(let elem of elems){ ... }`

Comment: Edited my questions with your suggestions, still no luck.

Comment: Not sure what's the `, html` after the selector, I've never used that. You should try without

Comment: Aaaaaah no, I know. The website is built dynamically with Ajax. Axios is getting you the original HTML, but then does not execute any script. To see what Axios brings you back, disable Javascript on the page and reload it. There's just a green infinite loader. You need a headless browser like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), that will render the full page with Javascript and Ajax calls. A simple HTTP call won't give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `img`s are there in the html, I can see them.

```
$('.exchange-card-small-logo img').get().map(img => $(img).attr('title'))
```

Comment: does this work for you? I get an empty array

Comment: It works with that html, you're probably getting blocked by the server. Try sending some request headers.